# Why rails doesn't update the "has_one" reference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I was trying to update a `has_one` reference but without deleting/destroying the old referenced record, but when I do this the reference to the new object isn't updated.

Example:

Classes:

```
ObjectClass
  has_one :child
end

Child
  belongs_to :object_class
end
```

Update:

```
object.update(child: new_child)
```

When I consulted the object after the update with `ObjectClass.last.child` the old child is returned, not the `new_child`. This only works if I run `object.child.destroy` before the update above.
`

Answer (score 0):

Do this from the other end.

```
new_child.update(object_class_id: object.id)
```

Comment: Yup, this will work, but I wanna know why the rails needs to remove the has_one referenced record to update by its own.

Comment: @MateusLuiz: how about `object.child = new_child` Maybe followed by `object.save` and/or `new_child.save`. I'm pretty sure this will work too.

Comment: @MateusLuiz: as to why the code from the question doesn't work like you expect it to, I don't know. Need a repro and some time for stepping through AR code.

Comment: The other solution will work too (you can consult the `Child.where(object_class: object_class)` and the child will be returned), but doesn't update the `has_one` referenced record either :/ , but thanks for the answer!!

Comment: But this can be fixed changing the has_one to has_many (I'm having an database modelation problem too), this question is more like a curiosity